# Dependency error while installing Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I want to install indigo on ubuntu 14.04 but i have dependency problem, maybe someone can help me out. for installation i followed instruction in ros [page](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu). just i can install ros_base. Also i tried current solution but they don't work!

```
vahid@vahid:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop : Depends: ros-indigo-rqt-common-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: ros-indigo-rqt-robot-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: ros-indigo-visualization-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: ros-indigo-viz but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

- 

```
vahid@vahid:~$ uname -m
x86_64
```

- 

```
vahid@vahid:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

i tried also with synaptic, but it wants to remove these packages:

```
cheese will be removed
compiz will be removed
compiz-gnome will be removed
compiz-plugins-default will be removed
gir1.2-totem-1.0 will be removed
gstreamer1.0-vaapi will be removed
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 will be removed
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 will be removed
libglapi-mesa:i386 will be removed
libglew1.10 will be removed
libglewmx1.10 will be removed
libgstreamer-vaapi1.0-0 will be removed
libnux-4.0-0 will be removed
libqt4-opengl:i386 will be removed
libqtwebkit4:i386 will be removed
libreoffice-ogltrans will be removed
libtotem0 will be removed
libunity-core-6.0-9 will be removed
libva-glx1 will be removed
libvisual-0.4-plugins will be removed
nux-tools will be removed
skype will be removed
skype-bin:i386 will be removed
totem will be removed
totem-mozilla will be removed
totem-plugins will be removed
ubuntu-desktop will be removed
unity will be removed
unity-lens-applications will be removed
xorg will be removed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203379/dependency-error-while-installing-indigo-on-ubuntu-14.04/) by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2015-02-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [minhaj falaki](https://answers.ros.org/users/32200/minhaj-falaki/) on 2017-10-10**:
Did you solve this problem.? Ryt now i am facing the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I met this problem yesterday, when I upgraded OpenCV and some ROS dependencies were broken. What I did is to use `aptitude` instead of `apt-get`. It is more intelligent, and can give you some suggestions to resolve the problem. Probably, you have some low-level packages version mismatch, so `apt-get` refuse to install ROS.

Try

```
$ sudo apt-get install aptitude

$ sudo aptitude install ros-indigo-desktop
```

Then you will see the lowest unmet dependencies as well as the suggestions. Pressing `n` to refuse its first suggestion, cause the first suggestion usually does nothing, `aptitude` will give your more suggestions every time you refuse. Choose one suggestion you like.

Also, you may have to run `$ sudo aptitude install ros-indigo-desktop` and select one suggestion several times to solve the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Steven Wei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31364/steven-wei/) with karma: 46 on 2017-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on 2017-11-04**:
Thank you bro